# How to initialize a uint64_t array to 0 in C++?

Tags: c++, uint64, atmelstudio

I'm using Atmel 6.2 and writing an application for Arduino. I have a problem with these lines of code:

```
int total = 3;
uint64_t myarray[total] = {};
```

It gives the following error

> error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

Why is this happening?

Comment: "Is not an integer *constant*", which it is not.

Comment: `total` must be `const`.

Comment: Array sizes must be compile-time constant.

Comment: Why do you think this is related to initializing to `0`?  Did you try some non-zero numbers?

Comment: Try this  uint64_t array[total] = {0};

Comment: @A.Shulzhenko, unfortunately, that won't work either.

Comment: The question title and the actual question don't match.

Comment: @stefaanv please have a loot at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
int total = 3;
uint64_t myarray[total] = {};
```

is a definition of a variable size array becaue the size of the array is not a compile-time constant expression.

Such kind of arrays is conditionally supported by C99. However this feature is not present in C++ (though some compilers can have their own language extensions that include this feature in C++) and the compiler correctly issues an error.

Either you should use a constant in the definition of the array for example like this

```
const int total = 3;
uint64_t myarray[total] = {};
```

or you should consider of using another container as for example `std::vector<uint64_t>` if you suppose that the ize of the array can be changed during run-time.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide compile-time constants (or `constexpr`s) as array size.

Use this:

```
const int total = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

"total" needs to be const.  Also I would prefer std::array to C-style arrays (just personal preference).

```
int const total = 3;

std::array<uint64_t, total> values = {};
```

If you need a dynamic array, use *std::vector*.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, you want to zero initialize or you want a fix to your Error.

As suggested you can make use of compile-time constant expression to fix error.

```
const int total = 3;
uint64_t myarray[total] = {};
```

To zero initialize you can use the following code.

```
std::fill_n(myarray, total, 0);
```

But, If you want a variable size array you can do it using pointers in the following manner.

```
int total = 3;

uint64_t  *myarray = new uint64_t [total]; // This will be created at run time
```